# Can Rhino parse HTML files

Tags: javascript, rhino

Can Rhino parse full HTML file with JavaScript in it?

Answer (score 3):

Rhino itself is a JavaScript engine not a full browser DOM implementation. The HTML parsing and DOM API must be provided by something else.

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is a program that emulates a web browser. It uses Rhino to run JavaScript on the page.